# JPQL query CASE WHEN is always false

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jpa

Hi i have a long query for a spring, java 8, hibernate, mysql application, which works as expected, except the last part, which sums the reserved items in store:

```
SELECT new example.package.RaktarKimutatasDTO(rk.cikkId.cikkName, 
CONCAT(SUM(rk.mennyisegMe1),' ', rk.me1.unitCode, ' / ', SUM(rk.mennyisegMe2),' ', rk.me2.unitCode, ' / ', SUM(rk.mennyisegMe3),' ', rk.me3.unitCode), 
CONCAT(AVG(rk.listaar), ' Ft'), 
CONCAT(rk.mennyisegMe1*rk.listaar, ' Ft'), 
rk.raktarId.raktarNeve, rk.cikkId.vtsz.vatCode, 
SUM(CASE WHEN rk.vevoiEntity IS NOT NULL THEN rk.mennyisegMe1 ELSE 0.0 END)) 
FROM RaktarkeszletEntity rk 
WHERE rk.raktarId.identifier IN ?1 AND rk.createDate<?2 AND (rk.bejovoszamlaEntity LIKE 'RB%' OR (rk.bejovoszamlaEntity LIKE 'BM%' AND rk.bevetel = TRUE)) 
GROUP BY rk.cikkId
```

The problem is, the SUM(CASE... ) part is always returns 0.
While if i use the (nearly) same query in in plain SQL, from Mysql workbench, it works as expected, sums the quantities for items which have "vevoiEntity" which is not null (so the reserved quantity).
vevoiEntity field in DB has int type, which can be null too.

The fields, called entity (except of course which used at FROM) are not entities, but simple integer. (previous developer had problems with naming too).

I've tried using more parentheses, tried " <> NULL" tried "vevoiEntity>0", etc but nothing helped, the case is always false, every other parts are perfect.

Why does it works differently in native SQL, and JPQL? I set hibernate.show_sql=true, and i saw that the generated query for the SUM CASE part, is just like the query that i used in workbench, so the translation seems to be ok.

plain SQL, (already working parts are left out) which works:

```
SELECT rk.cikk_id, SUM(CASE WHEN rk.vevoi_tetel_id IS NOT NULL THEN rk.mennyiseg_me_1 ELSE 0 END) as reserved  FROM nast_raktarkeszlet rk GROUP BY rk.cikk_id;
```

or:

```
SELECT rk.cikk_id, CONCAT(SUM(rk.mennyiseg_me_1),' ', rk.me_1, ' / ', SUM(rk.mennyiseg_me_2),' ', rk.me_2, ' / ', SUM(rk.mennyiseg_me_3),' ', rk.me_3), CONCAT(AVG(rk.listaar), ' Ft'), CONCAT(rk.mennyiseg_me_1*rk.listaar, ' Ft'), rk.raktar_id, rk.cikk_id, SUM(CASE WHEN IFNULL(rk.vevoi_tetel_id, 0) >0 THEN rk.mennyiseg_me_1 ELSE 0 END) FROM nast_raktarkeszlet rk GROUP BY rk.cikk_id
```

generated query:

```
select
        basecikkek1_.cikk_name as col_0_0_,
        concat(sum(rak0_.mennyiseg_me_1),
        ' ',
        men2_.unit_code,
        ' / ',
        SUM(rak0_.mennyiseg_me_2),
        ' ',
        men3_.unit_code,
        ' / ',
        SUM(rak0_.mennyiseg_me_3),
        ' ',
        men4_.unit_code) as col_1_0_,
        concat(avg(rak0_.listaar),
        ' Ft') as col_2_0_,
        concat(rak0_.mennyiseg_me_1*rak0_.listaar,
        ' Ft') as col_3_0_,
        rak5_.raktar_name as col_4_0_,
        vts7_.vat_code as col_5_0_,
        sum(case 
            when rak0_.szallitolevel_tetel_id is not null 
            or rak0_.kimeno_tetel_id is not null 
            or rak0_.vevoi_tetel_id<>0 then rak0_.mennyiseg_me_1 
            else 0 
        end) as col_6_0_ 
    from
        nast_raktarkeszlet rak0_ cross 
    join
        nast_cikkek basecikkek1_ cross 
    join
        nast_vtsz vts7_ cross 
    join
        nast_units men2_ cross 
    join
        nast_units men3_ cross 
    join
        nast_units men4_ cross 
    join
        nast_raktarak rak5_ 
    where
        rak0_.cikk_id=basecikkek1_.id 
        and basecikkek1_.vtsz=vts7_.id 
        and rak0_.me_1=men2_.id 
        and rak0_.me_2=men3_.id 
        and rak0_.me_3=men4_.id 
        and rak0_.raktar_id=rak5_.id 
        and (
            rak0_.raktar_id in (
                ? , ? , ? , ?
            )
        ) 
        and rak0_.create_date<? 
        and (
            rak0_.parentid like 'RB%' 
            or (
                rak0_.parentid like 'BM%'
            ) 
            and rak0_.bevetel=1
        ) 
    group by
        rak0_.cikk_id
```

Comment: Anytime NULL is used in a calculation or concat (or any function) for any field the entire result will be NULL.  Are all the values you you using in your formulas NOT NULL?  If not put a ISNULL(value, '')  (or 0 if number and so on)

Comment: Show the SQL that is generated then, as well as what you are using that works. You might want to simplify the query down to test the case statement, and then build it back up to see which part might be causing problems for that case statement

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(rk.vevoiEntity,0) >0 THEN rk.mennyisegMe1 ELSE 0 END) leads to runtime exception com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: I see that for mysql IFNULL should be used, so there is no error, just the usual 0 result...

Answer (score 0):

OMG my bad. The WHERE conditions are exclude the records that have non null "vevoientity"